# Noti - desktop notification is not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

In rails 4 project, I am trying to implement desktop notification feature by referring this http://api.notiapp.com/tutorials/rails. By following these procedure if I click on a link(setup_noti_path) it will leads to login page(Eg: https://notiapp.com/auth/fa574800-dbbb-1a5b-9c05-dfff043c405e). After login from this site it leads to my project page with flash message("Noti has now been configured for your account!"). Installed gem is `noti (1.0.2)`

Controller is like

```
class NotiAuthorisationsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    token = Noti::Token.create_request_token(noti_callback_url)
    session[:noti_rt] = token.request_token
    redirect_to token.redirect_url
  end

  def create
    token = Noti::Token.get_access_token(session[:noti_rt])
    current_hospital_admin.update_attribute(:noti_token, token)
    session[:noti_rt] = nil
    redirect_to root_path, :flash =>{:ok=>"Noti has now been configured for your account!"}
  end

end
```

Routes are,

```
get '/noti' => 'noti_authorisations#new', :as => 'setup_noti'
get 'noti/callback' => 'noti_authorisations#create', :as => 'noti_callback'
```

In rails console, I am trying to send notification by following method but it returns only true value.

```
notification = Noti::Notification.new
notification.title = "An example notification"
notification.text = "Some further information about this notification"
notification.deliver_to(user.noti_token)
```

Where can I add this above method inside my project? And this notification related code should check continuously inside rake task. Please help me to achieve the same.

Comment: Where have you put the key initialization `Noti.app = '4842e7ad-1cc5-66bf-8e4b-a9ec7ac3b828'`?

Comment: Also, `get 'noti/callback'` route should probably be `get '/noti/callback'` (note leading slash.)

Comment: I have initialized the key in `config/initializers/noti.rb`